# NSDate to string with format weekday numberday

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

how can i get a string with this format date: "Sunday 24"?
with this code

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatDate setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatDate setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd"];
NSString *date = [formatDate stringFromDate:startTime];
```

i have

> "sunday 24"

how can i get a capital letter?

Comment: When I drop this code into a command line app, the day name is Capitalized for me.  @EmptyStack's idea will work, but I am wondering if you're having a locale issue (are you working on an American / English locale or some other locale)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capitalize it explicitly.

```
NSString *date = [[formatDate stringFromDate:startTime] capitalizedString];
```

Comment: and for the time...if i want the hours:
"4 pm" or "2 am"?